# How add new items in listview from asynctask with jsoup

Tags: android, parsing, listview, android-asynctask, jsoup

I have one trouble...

I need pagenation after scroll, and it work, but then loading new items from new url page, older items deleted, but i want add new below older without deleted. I'm try using endlessadapter, but application are terminated.

**I found the [work example](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-listview-load-more-using-onscrolllistener-tutorial/), but I don't now how to add my code [there](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-listview-load-more-using-onscrolllistener-tutorial/)**

```
// code from onCreateView...
new ListViewLoad().execute("1");

// acynctask with loading
    private class ListViewLoad extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    String pNum;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        pNum= urls[0];
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://url.com?page="+pNum).get();
            for (Element table : doc.select("#search_result_container")) {
                for (Element row : table.select(".search_result_row")) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Elements app_title = row.select(".search_name");
                    Elements app_price = row.select(".search_name");
                    Elements app_released = row.select(".search_released");
                    Elements app_img = row.select(".search_capsule img[src]");
                    String app_img_Str = app_img.attr("src");
                    map.put("rank", app_title.text());
                    map.put("country", app_price.text());
                    map.put("population", app_released.text());
                    map.put("flag", app_img_Str);
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        listview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                    int scrollState) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int threshold = 1;
                int count = listview.getCount();

                if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    if (listview.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count
                            - threshold) {
                        String pNumNew = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(pNum)+1);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), pNumNew, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        new ListViewLoad().execute(pNumNew);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            }

        });
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this `arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();` hold your data?

Comment: I found the [work example](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-listview-load-more-using-onscrolllistener-tutorial/), but I don't now how to add my code [there](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-listview-load-more-using-onscrolllistener-tutorial/)

Comment: Try this, change `arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();`  ---> to ---> `if(arraylist == null) {arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();}`

Comment: OMG, this is worked! It so easy... Add you comment as answer pls...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already understood the `arraylist` variable keeps all your data. Every time the action that loads more data gets called, the variable gets initialized again. This works

```
if(arraylist == null) arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```